# Let's rename [babel], because people constantly use it instead of [babeljs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

[babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) grew very popular in the JS community. Every day at least a dozen new [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs)-related questions are being asked on SO. Every day, at least a couple of those questions are incorrectly tagged with [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel).

I just re-tagged something like about a hundred of those questions, and I did the same thing three months ago. And I believe that I'm not the only one doing it. Therefore, I think, we should rename [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel), so it will no longer be confused with [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs). [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) is not very popular right now, so renaming it won't hurt anyone.

So far, the best proposed rename for [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) is [python-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-babel) (suggested by **poke**). It's good because:

- It's clearly distinguishable from [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel)
- It's consistent with other python-namespaced libraries

Comment: They'll just keep using [babel], whatever you rename it to.  So just rename everything to [babel] and nobody can get it wrong anymore.  There's no overlap to worry about, these are libraries for very different tag communities.  Don't go off retagging a hundred questions please, surely they didn't actually need to get re-activated.

Comment: One fix would be to just rename [babel] to [babel-python] assuming the tag wiki is accurate and it is a python only library.  But @HansPassant's idea is a good one as long as people don't mind a dual-use tag.  You could just make [babeljs] a synonym of [babel]

Comment: @psubsee2003 yep, that's pretty much what I meant. I just wasn't sure about the right name, but [babel-python] looks fine.

Comment: @HansPassant some of those questions received almost no attention because of this incorrect tagging, because people on SO often look for questions with certain tags and completely ignore most of the other questions.

Comment: I think it should be [python-babel] then to match other python-namespaced libraries.

Comment: So, is there any progress on this? Generally speaking, what needs to happen in order for a tag to be renamed?

Comment: @DmitryShvedov there is no progress here yet. As for you question, we should get moderators attention and convince them that this change is a good thing. At the current stage we mostly need upvotes.

Comment: This still seems completely reasonable, nearly *5* years on. What happened to this proposal?

Comment: @zcoop98 - nothing, it just probably got swiped under the current of requests. Recent activity brought it back up, so we might get it closed. Folks, how about [tag:babel-py]? Tag [tag:python-babel] duplicates the main [tag:python] tag (that said, it is probably best to follow the current pattern of `python-*`)

Comment: There's even questions tagged with both [tag:babel] and [tag:babeljs]! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel+babeljs

Answer (score 35):

At this point, I think we're going to have to do the opposite here

[babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) is now *mostly* about babeljs. As such, the Python library is the outlier.

- 130 are [tagged with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D+%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0)
- 2 were tagged with only python-3.x
- 2 were tagged python-2.7
- 1914 [are not obviously tagged with JS or python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D+-%5Bjavascript%5D+-%5Bbabeljs%5D+-%5Bpython%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0)

As such we need to the Python questions retagged [python-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-babel). JS questions can stay as-is, since we can merge them into [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs)

Comment: Actually, when I search around 10 minutes ago for question tagged [babel] that *contained* the word "python," there were **321**. This seems to be falling rapidly ...284 at the time of this post.

Comment: Using my search above that excludes a bunch of tags, I added "python" and got 15 questions. Six seem related to node.js (which uses Python in npm). All cleaned now

Comment: That search gave me 114, just a few seconds ago.

Comment: The 130 Python-tagged ones have just been cleared

Comment: @Machavity, npm uses python? that's news to me since I don't have python installed.

Comment: @gman All I know is it was showing up in some npm questions. I don't know enough about npm to say why, tho. All I can say is it wasn't about Python Babel

Comment: @gman I'd assume python web projects using npm for clientside javascript (and wonder how many correctly need both python and npm tags), but am no more an expert than Machavity.

Comment: python is also used by npm for building native nodejs modules (aka C++ addons) with node-gyp

Answer (score 13):

Can we finally do something about it? Out of 579 questions tagged with [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel), 201 (over one third!) are also tagged with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). If you look at the [recently asked [babel] questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel), all the questions on the first page are about the JavaScript Babel.

Please rename the [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) tag to [python-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-babel). Also, it might be a good idea to rename [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) to [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel), since it's actually named Babel, not BabelJS.

Comment: Why not [tag:babeljs] => [tag:javascript-babel]?

Comment: @TinyGiant Because other JavaScript tools aren't using the [javascript-something] convention.

Comment: I think it's safe to leave `babeljs` as it is. But we should definitely do something about current `babel` tag.

Comment: By the way, only 3 out of top 10 related tags for [tag:babel] are actually babel-related (namely [tag:python], [tag:flask] and [tag:internationalization]). The rest are js-related and could only be used in [tag:babeljs] questions. So _one third_ is a huge underestimation.

Comment: I've just looked through 50 newest questions in [tag:babel] and found **only one** babel-related question. The rest were incorrectly tagged [tag:babeljs] questions.

Comment: While renaming `babeljs` to `babel` is formally correct, I think you overestimate users' ability to change. A tag named `babel` will be misused like before, especially if we turn around the meaning in one go.

Answer (score 10):

I've been mulling about this since long, and had been using this in the moderator room to fight for a mass-retag tool, so I'm really glad to see this happen! With the confession out of the way, here are some things that we need to tackle:

- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) + [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel). The 130 original questions that were related to the Python Babel, which needs to be retagged with [python-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-babel). This seems to be done already, so we can move on.
- Posts tagged with the other Python frameworks/projects. These should also be retagged with [python-babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-babel):

  - [5 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D%5Bjinja%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0) tagged [jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jinja2)
  - [13 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D%5Bflask%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0) tagged [flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flask)
  - [5 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D%5Bdjango%5D%20is%3Aq%20&mixed=0) tagged [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django)
- Now moving on to the JavaScript Babel plugin, just merging the remaining tags with [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) would do. However, we would need to clean up the existing tags and make sure that we're not missing out on any wrongly tagged Python posts.

  - Searching for posts without the top 10 related (JavaScript) tags, reduces the number of posts that we need to sift through from 1914 in the other post, to [just 390 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D%20-%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Breactjs%5D%20-%5Bwebpack%5D%20-%5Bbabeljs%5D%20-%5Bnpm%5D%20-%5Bnode.js%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%5Bvue.js%5D%20-%5Becmascript-6%5D%20-%5Btypescript%5D%20is%3Aq&mixed=0). I'm sure this can be further decreased by adding in more of the JavaScript framework tags.
  - A further way to refine is to also exclude those questions that contain the *mention* of the JavaScript frameworks in the body. This would put the [figure at 280 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbabel%5D%20-%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Breactjs%5D%20-%5Bwebpack%5D%20-%5Bbabeljs%5D%20-%5Bnpm%5D%20-%5Bnode.js%5D%20-%5Bangular%5D%20-%5Bvue.js%5D%20-%5Becmascript-6%5D%20-%5Btypescript%5D%20-%22javascript%22%20-%22reactjs%22%20-%22webpack%22%20-%22babeljs%22%20-%22npm%22%20-%22node.js%22%20-%22angular%22%20-%22vue.js%22%20-%22ecmascript-6%22%20is%3Aq&mixed=0).
  - Finally there are 23 posts that have just the [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) tag, and these should be reviewed once before the final tag merge.

Note that the point of this clean-up exercise is to not be a hundred percent sure that there aren't any wrongly tagged python-babel questions, but to make sure that the number of them are really low. It is totally fine if we miss a couple of python-babel posts, that get retagged to [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs). We would be finding them organically in the future, when we can retag them.

I would also add [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel) as a synonym for [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) post merge, as that would avoid the recreation of the tag. It might result in a few incorrectly tagged questions, but the curators of the [babeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babeljs) can definitely drop in and retag the smaller number of questions, as opposed to hacking it down to the ground again when it's recreated.

Comment: The subtags you mentioned were helpful. Missed those. I also found [tag:flask-babel] after I had retagged most. Not sure if we need a synonym there. A simple search for "python" in [babel] yields only 8 questions so I'm pretty satisfied we've covered most of the cases. Synonym is now up and merge coming later