# Replace [jest] tag with something more specific

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

[jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) tag refers to low-profile Java ElasticSearch library (1 question for the last month). [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) refers to popular JavaScript testing framework (466 question for the last month), while the framework's official name is Jest too.

Currently ~75% Jest framework questions are initially mistagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest), this takes a lot of work from the community. That [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) tag clearly suggests to not misuse it certainly doesn't help the situation: "Use the [jestjs] tag for questions related to the JavaScript testing framework".
The suggestion is to retag [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) questions with more specific tag like [jest-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest-java) or [jest-elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest-elasticsearch). [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) can optionally be made a synonym of `jestjs`.

This also was discussed in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325738/the-jest-tag-is-used-for-two-different-projects) but Jest framework was much less popular at the time of asking, no assistance from the staff was provided.

Comment: Even better: [tag:jestjs] can be made a synonym of [tag:jest] (with a wiki transfer of course) :) Given that ElasticSearch tags follow the pattern of prefixing `elasticsearch-*`, a simple solution in line with [established usage](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=elasticsearch-) would be [tag:elasticsearch-jest]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOCVR helped me clean the tag out of [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest) questions. I have synonymed [jest] to [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) and will merge later.

Answer (score 7):

**Proposal**

It is proposed to:

1. rename [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) into [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest)
2. make [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) a synonym of [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest)
3. transfer wiki from [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) to [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest)
4. add guidance to use [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), or [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)

---

**Alternative**

As [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399571/replace-jest-tag-with-something-more-specific/400002#comment787468_400002) by Braiam, an alternative could be:

1. rename [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) into [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest)
2. retag questions mentioned in step 2 with [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs)
3. add guidance to use [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) with [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), or [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)

---

**Reasoning**

1. As tagging [convention suggests](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1263219/tags-and-their-wikis-and-excerpts-that-are-similar-to-tag-name?tag=elasticsearch-), ElasticSearch-related tags are prefixed with `elasticsearch-*`.
2. Of 812 questions, only 146 are [tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest+elasticsearch) [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) and [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) (~18%) + 8 are [tagged with both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest+java+-elasticsearch) [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) and [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) exclusively (~1%). Contrary to that: 
   Firstly, 207 questions are [tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest+javascript+-node.js+-typescript+-ecmascript-6) [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) + [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) exclusively (~25%). 
   Secondly, 36 questions are [tagged with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest+typescript+-javascript+-node.js+-ecmascript-6) [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) + [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript), but not other langs (~4%). 
   Thridly, [5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest+ecmascript-6+-typescript+-javascript+-node.js) are tagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) + [ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6), but not with any above (~1%). 
   Fourthly, [30 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest+node.js+-ecmascript-6+-typescript+-javascript) are tagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) + [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), but not with any above (~4%). 
   Finally, counting non-exclusively, [431 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D%20or%20%5Becmascript-6%5D%20or%20%5Bjavascript%5D%20or%20%5Btypescript%5D%20and%20%5Bjest%5D) are tagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) and at least any of the abovementioned tags, making it ~53%.

   This shows it is more common (~34% exclusively, ~53% inclusively) to refer to the name of the JavaScript [testing framework](https://jestjs.io/) with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) than to ElasticSearch library.
3. Simply because [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) has no tag wiki, and [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) has one.
4. Wiki for [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) lacks usage guidance to add relevant language tag to help questions gain visibility. Currently, 5708 questions [do not have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs+-node.js+-javascript+-typescript+-ecmascript-6) relevant language tag associated with them (~49%) which might contribute to the high ratio of unanswered questions.

**Tag stats**

- [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) has 11 711 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs) with 47.2% unanswered
- [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) has 812 [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) with 44.5% unanswered

**Tag graphs**

This query suggests that the usage of [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) with [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) died down in the last couple of years:

[image: trend of jest with elasticsearch]

---

**Retagging effort**

Further refinement of the [query by Bhargav Rao](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400003/11407695) found [108 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjest%5D%20-%5Belasticsearch%5D%20is%3Aq%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20-%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Bnode.js%5D%20-%5Breact-native%5D%20-%5Breactjs%5D%20-%5Benzyme%5D%20-%5Btypescript%5D%20-%5Becmascript-6%5D) (67 after cleanup) for review (tagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest), but not either [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) or one of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)[node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js)[typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript)[ecmascript-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6)[react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-native)[reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs)[enzyme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/enzyme)[angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs)).

> With a help of a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1271474/questions-tagged-with-tag-but-not-by-any-of-tag-list?tag=jest&list=elasticsearch%2C%20puppeteer%2C%20webpack-2%2C%20webpack-dev-server%2C%20webpack%2C%20storybook%2C%20phantomjs%2C%20sweetalert2%2C%20react-redux%2C%20babel-jest%2C%20ionic-framework%2C%20javascript-intellisense%2C%20flowtype%2C%20redux-observable%2C%20redux-mock-store%2C%20tslint%2C%20koa%2C%20koa2%2C%20chai%2C%20redux-saga%2C%20redux%2C%20create-react-app%2C%20scala.js%2C%20sails.js%2C%20rxjs%2C%20jasmine%2C%20jsdom%2C%20istanbul%2C%20enzyme%2C%20ecmascript-6%2C%20typescript%2C%20vuejs2%2C%20javascript%2C%20reactjs%2C%20angular%2C%20angularjs%2C%20react-native%2C%20vue.js%2C%20node.js) I managed to narrow the query down to 41 question to review. Further narrowed to [39 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1271474/questions-tagged-with-tag-but-not-by-any-of-tag-list?tag=jest&list=elasticsearch-snapshot%2C%20spring-data-elasticsearch%2C%20elasticsearch%2C%20puppeteer%2C%20webpack-2%2C%20webpack-dev-server%2C%20webpack%2C%20storybook%2C%20phantomjs%2C%20sweetalert2%2C%20react-redux%2C%20babel-jest%2C%20ionic-framework%2C%20javascript-intellisense%2C%20flowtype%2C%20redux-observable%2C%20redux-mock-store%2C%20tslint%2C%20koa%2C%20koa2%2C%20chai%2C%20redux-saga%2C%20redux%2C%20create-react-app%2C%20scala.js%2C%20sails.js%2C%20rxjs%2C%20jasmine%2C%20jsdom%2C%20istanbul%2C%20enzyme%2C%20ecmascript-6%2C%20typescript%2C%20vuejs2%2C%20javascript%2C%20reactjs%2C%20angular%2C%20angularjs%2C%20react-native%2C%20vue.js%2C%20node.js). Narrowed to [38 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1271474/questions-tagged-with-tag-but-not-by-any-of-tag-list?tag=jest&list=aws-elasticsearch%2C%20elasticsearch-snapshot%2C%20spring-data-elasticsearch%2C%20elasticsearch%2C%20puppeteer%2C%20webpack-2%2C%20webpack-dev-server%2C%20webpack%2C%20storybook%2C%20phantomjs%2C%20sweetalert2%2C%20react-redux%2C%20babel-jest%2C%20ionic-framework%2C%20javascript-intellisense%2C%20flowtype%2C%20redux-observable%2C%20redux-mock-store%2C%20tslint%2C%20koa%2C%20koa2%2C%20chai%2C%20redux-saga%2C%20redux%2C%20create-react-app%2C%20scala.js%2C%20sails.js%2C%20rxjs%2C%20jasmine%2C%20jsdom%2C%20istanbul%2C%20enzyme%2C%20ecmascript-6%2C%20typescript%2C%20vuejs2%2C%20javascript%2C%20reactjs%2C%20angular%2C%20angularjs%2C%20react-native%2C%20vue.js%2C%20node.js). (<s>36</s>, <s>31</s>, <s>26</s> <s>19</s> <s>16</s> <s>9 left</s> done, added [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest)).

**September 2020**

As of now, the tag has crept back up, now around [65 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjest%5D%20-%5Belasticsearch%5D%20is%3Aq%20-%5Bangularjs%5D%20-%5Bjavascript%5D%20-%5Bnode.js%5D%20-%5Breact-native%5D%20-%5Breactjs%5D%20-%5Benzyme%5D%20-%5Btypescript%5D%20-%5Becmascript-6%5D) need review and retagging to [jest-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest-js) or [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest). Those are tagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest), but not [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) or one of the JavaScript-related tags (due to search query limits, you are better off using the query).

---

The problem that now needs to be resolved is the [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) tags that were added after the SEDE refresh and questions tagged with [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) *and* one of the JavaScript related tags (expanded [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1271474/questions-tagged-with-tag-but-not-by-any-of-tag-list?tag=jest&list=puppeteer%2C%20webpack-2%2C%20webpack-dev-server%2C%20webpack%2C%20storybook%2C%20phantomjs%2C%20sweetalert2%2C%20react-redux%2C%20babel-jest%2C%20ionic-framework%2C%20javascript-intellisense%2C%20flowtype%2C%20redux-observable%2C%20redux-mock-store%2C%20tslint%2C%20koa%2C%20koa2%2C%20chai%2C%20redux-saga%2C%20redux%2C%20create-react-app%2C%20scala.js%2C%20sails.js%2C%20rxjs%2C%20jasmine%2C%20jsdom%2C%20istanbul%2C%20enzyme%2C%20ecmascript-6%2C%20typescript%2C%20vuejs2%2C%20javascript%2C%20reactjs%2C%20angular%2C%20angularjs%2C%20react-native%2C%20vue.js%2C%20node.js&includeTags=yes) shows 617 questions that can be safely have [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) changed to [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs)).

Comment: Why not [jestjs] [elasticsearch-jest] so that there will be no confusion whatsoever?

Comment: @Braiam - you mean making [tag:jestjs] and [elasticsearch-jest] tags? Yes, I think that is a viable option as well. Added an alternative proposal to reflect that

Comment: Upvoted for Alternative

Comment: The answer isn't clear about current retagging strategy  being done

Comment: @TheMaster - hm? The review strategy stays the same - find questions tagged by [tag:jest] that are JavaScript-related ( i.e. with a [tag:reactjs] ) and retag them to [tag:jest-js]. This answer goes in pair with Bhargav's answer: first, review/retag the ambigously tagged questions, then the tag [tag:jest] will be safe to merge with [tag:jest-js]

Answer (score 5):

While [Oleg mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400002/4099593):

> rename [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) into [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest)

the solution isn't that straightforward. There are [658 [jest] questions currently](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjest%5D+-%5Belasticsearch%5D+-%22elasticsearch%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0) that do not have a elasticsearch tag or mention. That needs to be addressed first. We don't need to manually run through all the 658 posts, we just need to filter out to find the possible ones related to elastic search and add the [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest) tag to the ones that need them. This can be done by removing those that have a javascript, a reactjs or an enzyme tag on them. That leaves us around [130 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjest%5D+-%5Belasticsearch%5D+-%22elasticsearch%22+is%3Aq+-%5Bjavascript%5D+-%5Bnode.js%5D+-%5Breact-native%5D+-%5Breactjs%5D+-%5Benzyme%5D&mixed=0) which need to be checked. We need to go through these manually, and add the [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest) tag.

Once that's done, we need to update the ones that already have a [elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch) tag on them. There used to be a CM script that could have been used to add the [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest) in mass to the 146 posts with both the tags, but given that Shog no longer works for the company, we do not have access to that tool. For now we would need to manually open up the 146 posts and add  the [elasticsearch-jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/elasticsearch-jest) tag to those.

After these two cleanups, you can then proceed with merging [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest), which would then be left with just the jestjs questions, with [jestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jestjs). [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) will die at the end of the merge.

Please do address this as soon as possible, let [jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jest) not become a new [babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/babel).

Comment: Babel thing could be prevented by prefixing with python, no?

Comment: Yes, the solution is easy, but the volume makes it hard. Babel is worse than this because there's around 1500 posts which are related to the original Babel, and the remaining which are about BabelJS. Going through that amount of posts is very hard.

Comment: As someone said, solutions are easier when you aren't going against the current. Rename first, fix later, since every day we don't deal with the issue, it becomes bigger ;)

Comment: @BhargavRao - maybe it is time to respark the discussion on [Babel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310149/lets-rename-babel-because-people-constantly-use-it-instead-of-babeljs). I can provide some supplementary data and either add to the initial question or start a new one (whichever is better) - I agree with Braiam here, [tag:babel] can become [tag:python-babel] or be postfixed: [tag:babel-py] (or [tag:babel-python])

Comment: While I don't really like that direction, @Braiam, I suppose we aren't left with other options.

Comment: Btw, this leaves us with 107 only if we [exclude](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjest%5D+-%5Belasticsearch%5D+-%22elasticsearch%22+is%3Aq+-%5Bjavascript%5D+-%5Bnode.js%5D+-%5Breact-native%5D+-%5Breactjs%5D+-%5Benzyme%5D+-%5Btypescript%5D) those tagged with [tag:jest] + [tag:typescript] as well. [103](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjest%5D+-%5Belasticsearch%5D+-%22elasticsearch%22+is%3Aq+-%5Bjavascript%5D+-%5Bnode.js%5D+-%5Breact-native%5D+-%5Breactjs%5D+-%5Benzyme%5D+-%5Btypescript%5D+-%5Becmascript-6%5D) without [tag:ecmascript-6]

Comment: The one I shared was just for a start, @OlegValter, feel free to improvise on that. Anything around 100~150 should be easy to handle.

Comment: @BhargavRao - yes, thank you, I only wanted to refine it further, we can also exclude those that are tagged with [tag:angularjs], but the query got over the limit, maybe a SEDE will help

Comment: I will link you how we dealt with a tag that resisted to die in Unix and Linux: [Unfortunately, the questions keep coming in. I try to catch them early but some always fall through the cracks. Please blacklist install so that we can clean up the remaining occurrences.](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2532/41104). Note, I'm not saying that we need to blacklist these tags, but a blunt action to stop the tide would be helpful.