# Renaming [slate] because it is often used instead of [slate.js]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The tag [slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate) was created for a python library, but is often used for the slate javascript editor.

- `slate` was created for https://pypi.org/project/slate/, but is mostly used for https://docs.slatejs.org/
- [slatejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slatejs) and [slate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate.js) were created both for https://docs.slatejs.org/

So I would propose to

1. rename the `slate` tag to `slate.py`
2. and make `slatejs` a synonym to `slate.js`

What do you think (I'm not experienced in naming of tags)?

Comment: Looks good to me. slatejs -> slate.js also makes sense, at least since the title on Google appears as `slate.js`. (if the project preferred slatejs to slate.js, the synonym should've probably been the other way around for consistency reasons across platforms. Obligatory disclaimer that I found this out from about 3 minutes of looking around, so I could be wrong)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We're already [going through something similar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310149/4099593) for another Python library where the JavaScript library of the same name has started to take complete control. Fortunately, this is much much smaller than the other one.

For this effort, I agree pretty much with your proposal, but with a small change to your first step. Looking at the [slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate) tag, it seems like the majority of the questions are about the JavaScript variant rather than the python one. So instead of renaming [slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate) to [slate.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate.py), we I would propose [retagging the posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bslate%5D+%5Bpython%5D+&mixed=0) that have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag with them to [python-slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-slate) (which follows the convention that we're following with the other python library tags), and then merge [slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate) with [slate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate.js). The second step would then be the same.

Therefore, the steps would be:

1. Retag the posts in [slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate) referring to the Python Slate library with [python-slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-slate).
2. Merge [slate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate) with [slate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate.js)
3. Merge [slatejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slatejs) with [slate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slate.js)

Comment: This sounds like the best solution, I just feared that this would be too much of work.