# Merge tags into GSAP

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I currently work for GreenSock, the makers of the GreenSock Animation Platform (GSAP). Previous versions of GSAP had different names and purposes (I won't bore you with what the differences are) and each has their own tag here on SO. As of GSAP 3.0 which came out in November of last year, all of those different versions have been deprecated/consolidated into a single GSAP core file.

Can we please synonymize the tags [tweenmax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tweenmax), [tweenlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tweenlite), [timelinemax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timelinemax), [timelinelite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timelinelite), and [greensock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greensock) (because the only GreenSock product commonly asked about is GSAP) so that there's only the singular tag [gsap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsap)? As it is, having these additional tags only adds confusion to users and makes it harder to keep track of all new GSAP questions. All of the old versions can accurately be called GSAP as they were each forms or parts of GSAP.

A potential note of interest is that there was an old version of GSAP for Flash. In terms of tagging, questions *should* have a [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flash) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag along with them when relevant. But both the Flash and JavaScript versions are called GSAP.

If GreenSock releases other products in the future then they may warrant their own tag at that time.

Comment: I've [started things off](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gsap/synonyms) I think you have enough rep in the tag to vote for the synonyms.

Comment: Could we not use the acronym by itself? Maybe [greensap-ap] so it's clear? Acronym-only tags have a poor history if another project comes along with the same one. We can synonym [gsap] to it

Comment: Sorry if I don't know the history, but by "*As of GSAP 3.0 which came out in November of last year, all of those different versions have been deprecated/consolidated into a single GSAP core file.*", did you mean that the older versions are now gone, non-functional, or rebranded? While it's good to think about future usage, how about historical questions before GSAP 3.0? Will those still make sense after the synonym?

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes, old questions will still make sense. The only downside is that people who want to use the old version and are searching for questions on Stack overflow wouldn't be able to filter by tag as much as much.

Comment: @Machavity The library is extremely well known in the web animation world as GSAP (not as much for what it means) so using greensock-ap as the tag may bring some confusion. Plus wouldn't we still have to switch things around if something else use the GSAP acronym anyway? GSAP has been around 12+ years and I'm unaware of a similar acronym in or outside of programming.

Comment: @ZachSaucier It would be a synonym of the longer tag to prevent that. If something else came along with GSAP, they'd need a more specific tag. We recently had to do that with [the babel tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310149) and create [tag:python-babel]

Comment: @Machavity I would consider GSAP to be the more appropriate name vs GreenSock. However, I do think the two should be synonymized (if they aren't already) to each other in *some* direction.

Comment: having used GSAP from Flash days with ActionScript 2.0 and ActionScript 3.0 and then into the JavaScript world, I endorse this. upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags have been synonymized! Thanks all.

Comment: Since there was a Meta and apparently the community voted the synonyms in, I went ahead and merged them. Everything is now tagged [gsap]