# Updating product tags after a name change - Grakn + Graql

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Our company Grakn Labs, has changed names to Vaticle and with this change, we are also changing our database and query language name, how can I request for a new tag to be created/old tag renamed?

[grakn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grakn) should become [typedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedb) AND
[graql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graql) should become [typeql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeql)

We could go the route of adding/requesting a tag synonym but we don't want to have [grakn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grakn) + [graql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graql) live on. We would prefer to rename the old tags.

Comment: Merging the tags will do both. For people who don't know the new name right away, the synonyms allows them to find the tags, so I wouldn't recommend you just get rid of the synonyms.

Answer (score 6):

[typedb] and [typeql] are a bit generic. For instance, a quick search yields [some unlaunched project that owns the domain name](https://typeql.com/) (I hope your legal-type peoples have that all sorted).

I created [vaticle-typedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaticle-typedb) and gave you a synonym for both [grakn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/grakn) and [typedb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typedb) (keeps people from making a generic tag and overlapping with anything else that might share the name).

I also made [vaticle-typeql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaticle-typeql) and gave you a synonym for both [graql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graql) and [typeql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typeql).

---

Rather than continue this in comments, let me see if I can explain this in detail and put the issue to rest.

As I noted above, someone has ostensibly laid claim to TypeQL (they registered that domain in 2016). They might not ever do anything with it, but I've seen more times than I care to count where [someone else makes a project with the same name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310149/2370483) and suddenly the tag meaning changes because the new project is more popular than the old.

Vaticle is the first mover here so I'm trying to ensure than *nobody else can confuse the tag usage*. If you [look at the synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vaticle-typedb/synonyms), you'll note that attempting to tag [typedb] maps to this one. That ensures that Vaticle owns this term. Period. Nobody can take this tag away from you now.

> The definition of a "trademarked term" means no one else is allowed to use the term.

I think you're missing something practical here: enforcement. "typedb" is a fairly generic thing (type + db). Assuming they give you the trademark, are you going to bet that nobody else ever comes up with this and starts some Open Source project with the same name? I'm trying to plan for how this impacts Stack Overflow because users can (and will) come here to ask about it (which eventually means more Meta posts, cleanup efforts, etc.)

You might own the trademark, but now you get to track folks down, send them scary lawyer letters and try to extricate your project from the meaning of the other(s). That takes time and effort (ask the Mozilla foundation how that went with changing from "Phoenix" to "Firefox"). And all that takes time and money. Time that people will still be mis-tagging things here, confusing projects, etc.

> You don't see the TypeScript being tagged as "Microsoft TypeScript" do you?

No, but you're not comparing apples to apples. TypeScript has been around since 2012 and it's widely known now. The paint [isn't even dry on your new corporate website](https://vaticle.com/), which still directs you to the old one with your old name. Oh, and [we removed the [microsoft] tag as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284167/blacklist-the-microsoft-and-apple-tags)

This isn't some sort of slight. I'm trying to think of how best to serve the community here and ensuring that your tag remains problem free. That's how we avoid tag confusion around here (see [php-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-carbon), [graphite-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/graphite-carbon) and [macos-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/macos-carbon)). The tag is as clear as I can make it for the users who will never even see the excerpt. Putting your name in front does that.

Comment: Thank you and to answer your question - we now own global trademarks for TypeDB and TypeQL. This is the name of our product and query language, so would need to be `typedb` and `typeql`.

Comment: If you could review this again, @machavity, that would be great.

Comment: I'm not inclined to change them to something more generic. If someone does put out another TypeQL (not unreasonable to assume) they'll start misusing the tag, regardless of if you own the trademark. This way avoids any problems down the road, and you have the synonym of the generic term as well. Nobody should have problems finding the tags, and I updated the descriptions as well.

Comment: there will not be another TypeQL as it would be an infringement on the trademarks, so not sure if your reasoning aligns. Again, this is the name of our product and we want to avoid having the old name be visible.

Comment: Please see further reading on the legality of trademark rights: https://cyber.harvard.edu/metaschool/fisher/domain/tm.htm

Comment: The definition of a "trademarked term" means no one else is allowed to use the term. Doing so would be illegal. Also, your picking of TypeDB and TypeQL being too generic is a bit arbitrary. Those terms are unique in the industry as it stands (the typeql project you found is outdated and dormant), and they are as generic as "TypeScript". You don't see the TypeScript being tagged as "Microsoft TypeScript" do you? Even though, Microsoft is the company behind it. TypeDB and TypeQL are unique names and will remain being unique names -- legally.

Comment: @haikalpribadi That's a *very* naive (and inaccurate) view of trademark law, particularly when the entire world is taken into account. When searching the United States Patent and Trademark Office, I found *neither term*. The only things registered are "[GRAKN](//tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=87406759&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch)" and "[GRAQL](//tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=87334880&caseType=SERIAL_NO&searchType=statusSearch)", registered to Grakn Labs. I do see that such trademark *applications* were filed in the UK on 2021-04-12. (continued)

Comment: Neither of those UK trademark applications have been approved at this time (both have the status of "Examination"). While a trademark might get protection in one country or a few countries (and even then, it's commonly limited, with some types of duplication possible and legal), worldwide protection is a *much* different issue. I'd also note that the company's website doesn't include the trademark or registered symbols on those terms, so there's no indication that the company has, or is trying to enforce, such a trademark claim.

Comment: Please don't use flags to indicate that comments are "incorrect", particularly not when one of the moderators here is trying to be helpful. If you don't agree with the decision here, feel free to use the contact form at the bottom of any page and ask to talk with a Community Manager about how we can help you support your product here on SO. cc @nydatamind007

Comment: I made a more expansive edit explaining my position. I'm not trying to slight anyone, but neither am I inclined to change this for the reasons I explained above. If that's not good enough, I would direct you to the contact form, as Catija (a Community Manager) mentioned.